# How can I "reset" the \n alignment in order to print aligned at the first line?

Tags: c, windows, printf, stdout

This function has to print the stacks of cards of a solitaire game.

```
void print_stacks(Stack *stacks){
    char moretab[20] = {0};
    Stack *currentPtr = &(stacks[0]);
    for (size_t i=1;i<10;++i){
        while (currentPtr != NULL){
            printf("%s%s\n%s",currentPtr->cardd.face,currentPtr->cardd.suit,moretab);
            currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
        }
        strcat(moretab,"\t");
        currentPtr = &(stacks[i]);
    }
}
```

If you want, here is the complete code: https://hastebin.com/iguteleqiq.cpp

I have this output for example:

```
> cmd /c .\"solitaire.exe" 

8♣

        2♣
        Q♣

                9♠
                2♦
                2♥

                        Q♥
                        6♠
                        7♠
                        J♥

                                Q♦
                                10♦
                                7♦
                                J♦
                                4♣

                                        K♦
                                        4♠
                                        2♠
                                        A♥
                                        3♣
                                        J♣

                                                9♥
                                                3♦
                                                8♠
                                                10♥
                                                K♠
                                                3♠
                                                8♥

                                                        A♣
                                                        A♦
                                                        8♦
                                                        J♠
                                                        9♣
                                                        4♥
                                                        9♦
                                                        5♥

                                                                K♣
                                                                6♦
                                                                A♠
                                                                3♥
                                                                4♦
                                                                K♥
                                                                5♠
                                                                10♠
                                                                5♣
```

Expected output:

```
> cmd /c .\"somerset.exe" 
8♣      2♣      9♠      Q♥      Q♦        etc etc etc
        Q♣      2♦      6♠      10♦
                2♥      7♠      7♦
                        J♥      J♦
                                4♣
```

How could I have all these stacks of cards aligned at the same first line? I tried to flush stdout, but doesn't work. What can I do to in order achieve this? I'm not very experienced.

Comment: What does "aligned at the same first line" mean exactly? Can you please show the expected output so that there will be no doubt.

Comment: You keep adding tabs to the start of your string: `strcat(moretab,"\t");`  "Reset the string" and you should be fine :)  Q: What do you want the tabs for in the first place?  Q: If you need more help, could you provide a more complete [example](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: @kaylum updated the thread.

Comment: If you don't want to move to the next line, then don't print a newline.  To achieve the output you want, it looks like your best bet is to print row by row instead of column by column.

Comment: You need `\r`. Try: `printf("%s%s\n\r%s",currentPtr->cardd.face,currentPtr->cardd.suit,moretab);`

Comment: @HugoCunha does not work.

Comment: Can you post the remaining code?

Comment: @HugoCunha posted.

Comment: @HugoCunha  He wants a vertical carriage return that takes the cursor back to the top of the screen.  John had the right idea.  Here is a working example: https://onlinegdb.com/ryi9K95SP

Comment: It seems like we came up with similar solutions. 

https://onlinegdb.com/SJkVfj9BD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @JohnBollinger suggested in the comments, you need to print the data row by row. The stacks are the columns so you need to keep track of your place in 9 different stacks.  If you had an array of 9 stack pointers initialized to the top of the 9 stacks you could loop through those 9 pointers and print the current item in each stack to make a row.  Then loop until there is nothing left to print.

Something like this:

```
// you need to #include <stdbool.h> or change finished to an int
void print_stacks(Stack *stacks){
    // make 9 stack pointers
    Stack *currentPtr[9];
    // point them to the first 9 stacks
    for (size_t i=0;i<9;++i){
        currentPtr[i] = &(stacks[i]);
    }
    // loop through printing one row at a time
    bool finished;
    do{
        finished=true;
        // print the current item from each of the 9 stack pointers
        for (size_t i=0;i<9;++i){
            if (currentPtr[i] != NULL){
                printf("%s%s",currentPtr[i]->cardd.face,currentPtr[i]->cardd.suit);
                currentPtr[i] = currentPtr[i]->nextPtr;
                // we printed something so we aren't finished
                finished=false;
            }
            printf("\t");
        }
        printf("\n");
    // loop until we are finished
    } while (!finished);
}
```

Try it online: https://onlinegdb.com/SyPZoqcBw